# Apply label while checking in the code in TFS 2010

Tags: tfs

When I am checking in the code how do I need to checking the code against the label? I mean to say

I have Dev Branch i created two labels Release 1.1 and Release 1.2 .. I need to work on these releases separately Can i check int he code only to Release 1.1 Label? does when I am going get the specific version on my release 1.2 does Release 1.1 changes will comes? I did this but I am getting the conflicts and it was applying to the same branch(DEV)  Instead of label?

Answer (score 1):

Labels are just placeholders and cant be checked in against. You would need to check in, and then manually alter the label to include the changes.

For your circumstance I would recommend that you create a Branch from the label and check your changes in there.

Comment: Actually, this seems more like a reason to use two branches (off the DEV branch), and to not use labels at all.

Comment: That was what I intended to saY John.. 